# Swift - Round Edges Extension only round 2 edges on 4" Devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

i am working on an App with Round Edges Extension. It works fine, except on 4" Devices (See Image) What can I do?

Thanks!

Here´s my Code

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the Image]

Comment: You can press `cmd`+`shift`+`4` and then `space` and then select a window to only take a screenshot of that window. Improves your image ;)

Comment: use "self.layer.maskToBound = true"